# It does not show me any output on console screen. What may be the problem

Tags: javascript

When I click The button it does not show me any output on the console window

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" id="Click me">Click me</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
  </body>
</html>
```

->js

```
var printNumber=document.getElementById('Click me');
printNumber=document.addEventListener('Click',showNo);
function showNo() {
  console.log('I was Clicked');
}
```

Comment: typo: it should be `click` not `Click`

Comment: #Nick Parsons Still I can't see an output on the console screen

Answer (score 3):

You have a few issues with your code.
Firstly you need to close your `<script>` tag in your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Secondly, your `id` shouldn't have spaces in it. You can change it to something like `btn-click`:

```
<button type="button" id="btn-click">Click me</button>
```

And then make sure to target it properly in your Javascript:

```
var printNumber=document.getElementById('btn-click');
```

Thirdly, your event name should be lowercase (as Javascript is case-sensitive), so change `"Click"` to `"click"`

Lastly, you want to add the `click` event listener to your button, which is stored in the variable `printNumber`. At the moment you are adding the event listener to your `document` and not the button. To add it to your button you can use:

`printNumber.addEventListener("click", showNo); // add click event listener to button`

See working example below:

```js
var printNumber = document.getElementById('btn-click'); // change id selector
printNumber.addEventListener('click', showNo); // change 'Click' to 'click'
function showNo() {
  console.log('I was Clicked');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Awesome button</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" id="btn-click">Click me</button> <!-- change id --> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>  <!-- close script -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `click` not `Click`!

> *JavaScript is a `case-sensitive` language. This means that the language keywords, variables, function names, and any other identifiers must always be typed with a consistent capitalization of letters.*

```js
var printNumber=document.getElementById('Click me');
printNumber=document.addEventListener('click',showNo);
function showNo() {
  console.log('I was Clicked');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" id="Click me">Click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had one typo `Click`  which is supposed to be `click`.

```
`printNumber=document.addEventListener('Click',showNo);` 
             ^^^^^^^^
```

you should add event listener to that particular element not to the complete document.

```js
var printNumber=document.getElementById('Click_me');
printNumber.addEventListener('click',showNo);
function showNo() {
  console.log('I was Clicked');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" id="Click_me">Click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```